# Does using Comparison Operators works same as ctype_digit() or is_numeric() all the time?

Tags: php

For a variable like the following `$p = $_GET['page']`

In conditions like the following

```
if ($p > 0)
if ($p < 0)
if ($p >= 0)
if ($p <= 0)
if ($p == 0)
```

does it work same as

```
if (ctype_digit($p)){//Logic}
//or...
if (is_numeric($p)){//Logic}
```

Comment: I don't get the question...

Comment: @FirstOne Sometimes i have to assure that the value of variable is a `number` so i use `ctype_digit($var)` or `is_numeric($var)`, But sometimes if i used `if($var > 0)` it works same as the previous functions since a letter isn't `>` or `<` a number so i wonder if there any need to use functions.

Comment: The [PHP loose comparison rules are pretty well documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), including the [rules for casting strings to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: And it isn't like either of your suggestions, more like `if ((int) $p)`

Comment: My suggestion is pass in the right datatype for the job. If you cannot control what is being passed in then check what it is first. PHP is super flexible with casting for us but when it comes to trying to find a bug in your code it becomes very obvious how that can bite you in the...

Comment: @nerdlyist So instead of checking if value is an `integer` or not, I just force it to be an inter in the variable itself `$p = (int) $_GET['page'];`, So i don't have to check it with `ctype_digit()` or `is_numeric()` functions at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is pass in the right datatype for the job. So if you need number pass that to this code.

If you cannot control what is being passed in then check what it is first. This makes you take a second look when code starts to break. I would use `is_numeric` because it know negatives and floats unlike `ctype_digit`

```
is_numeric("-10"); //TRUE 
ctype_digit("-10"); //FALSE
is_numeric("12.10"); //TRUE 
ctype_digit("12.10"); //FALSE
```

So in the end you would want to do something like:

```
$p = $_GET['page'];

if(is_numeric($p)){
    $p = (int)$p;
    //Do stuff with an int
} else {
    //Not sure what should happen here...
}
```

PHP is super flexible with casting for us but when it comes to trying to find a bug in your code it becomes hard to find when you act like everything is coming in good ie `if($p>0){}` seems like you know you have a number and I would keep looking elsewhere.